# Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server, I am trying to configure a new PC for an existing user (whose existing PC is shutdown) but when I try to connect the new PC with the same credentials I receive a message from Active Directory that a computer with the same name is already connected. How do I get Active Directory to refresh and recognise that the old PC is shutdown so that the new PC can connect?

Comment: Reset the computer's account in AD?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a domain administrator or at least member of the Account Operators group. Use the **Active Directory Users and Computers** management console to remove the said computer account.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754624.aspx